# How to add br (line feed) to a contenteditable div by ctrl + enter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$("#contenteditable").keydown(function(e) {
    var last = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            let brNode = document.createElement('br');
            let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            
            if (!range.endContainer.nextElementSibling) {
               last = true;
            }
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(brNode);
            range.collapse();
            
            if (last) {
               let brNode = document.createElement('br');
               range.insertNode(brNode);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contenteditable" contenteditable="true">Hello this is input</div>
```

At first glance it seems that it works, but when you press enter on a word, a break appears and not a hyphen
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tstRG.jpg)

Please, help tell me how it's fixed, for example, at web.telegram.org

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$("#contenteditable").keydown(function(e) {
    //.var last = false;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /****************************/
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        /****************************/
    
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
        
            let selStart = function(inp) {
              const sel = window.getSelection();
              if (sel.rangeCount === 0)
                  return -1;

              const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
              const preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
              preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(inp);
              preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
              return preCaretRange.toString().length - sel.toString().length;
            } (this);
            
            let brNode = document.createElement('br');
            let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode(brNode);
            range.setStartAfter(brNode);
            
            //last = selStart === this.textContent.length;
            if (selStart === this.textContent.length) {
               let brNode = document.createElement('br');
               range.insertNode(brNode);
               range.setStartAfter(brNode);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contenteditable" contenteditable="true">Hello this is input</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but now the break will work if we press ctr-enter at the end once, then remove it and press it again, can we get rid of it too?